# ejecutar funcion al pulsar enter

Tags: javascript

hola tengo este codigo y por mas que los pruebo , la funcion que detecta la tecla no me lo ejecuta cuando pulso enter.

```
//selecionamos todos los elementos html con los que vamos a trabajar
let moneda = document.querySelector("#moneda");
let resultado = document.querySelector("#resultado22");
let boton = document.querySelector("#boton");

function calcular(valor) {
  valor = moneda.value * 3000;
  //FUNCION LOCALESTRING PONE LOS PUNTOS A LOS NUMEROS
  return valor.toLocaleString("es-ES");
}

function insertarValor() {
  boton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    //la funcion insertAdjacentHTML con la opcion beforeend sirve para añadir un elemento al html justo debajo del elemento que le pasemos antes del punto
    resultado.insertAdjacentHTML(
      "beforeend",
      `<div class="res">${calcular()} €</div>`
    );
    // aqui indicamos que al pulsar el boton el valor de maneda va ser un string vacio
    moneda.value = "";
  });
}

function inicio() {
  calcular();
  insertarValor();
}
moneda.onkeydown = teclado;
function teclado(tecla) {
  let codigo = tecla.keyCode;
  codigo === 13 ? calcular() : "error";
}
inicio();
```

---

este es el html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script defer src="index.js"></script>
    <title>MONEDAS</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="contenedor">
      <div class="titulo">
        <h1>Conversor Monedas</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="monedas">
        <input id="moneda" type="text" placeholder="introduce moneda" />
      </div>

      <div class="resultado" id="resultado22"></div>

      <div class="convertir">
        <button id="boton">Convertir</button>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que pude entender, lo que intentas es que tanto al hacer click como al presionar enter se lance el cálculo y se agregue la línea...

Para hacer esto en vez de hacer un onclick y un onkeydown lo que hice es eliminar la función de keydown, y la de click cambiarla por onsubmit, así que el input y el botón los encerré en una etiqueta form de forma que tanto con click en el botón como con enter, se llama al listener del submit y agrega un registro, tampoco sería necesaria la función que lo encerraba, ni la función inicio en su totalidad ni llamarla al final.

Quedaría algo así:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script defer src="index.js"></script>
    <title>MONEDAS</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="contenedor">
      <div class="titulo">
        <h1>Conversor Monedas</h1>
      </div>
      <form action="" id="myForm">
        <div class="monedas">
          <input id="moneda" type="text" placeholder="introduce moneda" />
        </div>

        <div class="resultado" id="resultado22"></div>

        <div class="convertir">
          <button id="boton">Convertir</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </section>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

El Script quedaría así:

```
//selecionamos todos los elementos html con los que vamos a trabajar
let moneda = document.querySelector("#moneda");
let resultado = document.querySelector("#resultado22");

// Acá capturamos el formulario directamente, para luego hacer algo con su evento submit.
let myForm = document.querySelector("#myForm");

function calcular(valor) {
  valor = moneda.value * 3000;
  //FUNCION LOCALESTRING PONE LOS PUNTOS A LOS NUMEROS
  return valor.toLocaleString("es-ES");
}

// Acá capturamos el evento submit y agregamos una calculo a la lista.
  myForm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
      // Esta línea evita que se recargue la página al hacer submit.
    event.preventDefault();
    //la funcion insertAdjacentHTML con la opcion beforeend sirve para añadir un elemento al html justo debajo del elemento que le pasemos antes del punto
    resultado.insertAdjacentHTML(
      "beforeend",
      `<div class="res">${calcular()} €</div>`
    );
    // aqui indicamos que al pulsar el boton el valor de maneda va ser un string vacio
    moneda.value = "";
  });

// Estas funciones tampoco son necesarias, el listener de líenea 13 se ejecuta solo si no está dentro de una función.
// Y calcular se llama en la línea 18.
// function inicio() {
//   calcular();
//   insertarValor();
// }

// Esta función está mal, nunca captura el evento onkeydown, no hay un listener, pero en realidad no es necesaria.
// moneda.onkeydown = teclado;
// function teclado(tecla) {
//   let codigo = tecla.keyCode;
//   codigo === 13 ? calcular() : "error";
// }

// inicio();
```

Todo lo comentado con // es lo que no sería necesario.

---

Si de todos modos quieres hacerlos por separado enter y click, podría ser algo así.

HTML tal cual lo tenés, sin cambios, sin form, sin onsubmit.

Script:

```
//selecionamos todos los elementos html con los que vamos a trabajar
let moneda = document.querySelector("#moneda");
let resultado = document.querySelector("#resultado22");
let boton = document.querySelector("#boton");

function calcular(valor) {
  valor = moneda.value * 3000;
  //FUNCION LOCALESTRING PONE LOS PUNTOS A LOS NUMEROS
  return valor.toLocaleString("es-ES");
}

// Acá capturamos el evento click y agregamos una calculo a la lista.
boton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    insertarCalculo();
});


// Acá capturamos el evento keydown y y si se presiona Enter llama a insertarCalculo().
moneda.addEventListener("keydown", function teclado(tecla) {
  let codigo = tecla.keyCode;
  codigo === 13 ? insertarCalculo() : "error";
});

// Una única función que llamaremos tanto con el Click como al presionar Enter.
function insertarCalculo() {
  //la funcion insertAdjacentHTML con la opcion beforeend sirve para añadir un elemento al html justo debajo del elemento que le pasemos antes del punto
  resultado.insertAdjacentHTML(
    "beforeend",
    `<div class="res">${calcular()} €</div>`
  );
  // aqui indicamos que al pulsar el boton el valor de maneda va ser un string vacio
  moneda.value = "";
}
```